# how to make program to take input from gui rather than command promt

Tags: c++, 3d, 3d-rendering

i am working on skeleton climbing algorithm for my .stl file generation, am getting the output. but for this code i need to pass arguments from the command prompt how will i pass arguments without opening command prompt?? are is it possible to pass input to this code from gui?? please give me some suggestions .... you can find the complete code from the given link...

http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~ttwong/papers/asc/asc.html

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your OS normally provides a mechanism to pass command lines to a file.

- What OS are you on ? [ANS: Windows 7]
- How do you plan to start your app (e.g. double click an icon?)
- Do args change from run to run ? (perhaps you need to make your app ask for the required info rather than getting it from the "command line")

Comment: i am working on windows 7 , as soon the code in the above link is compiled it generate .exe file ... as from the readme document of the author of this code i execute the program from command promt . i think  a clear documentation provided in the link will give clear picture...

Comment: Most people (myself included) don't follow external links.

Comment: Main point is: do the args change each time you run? if they do then you need the app to have a window to "get" the args (or a wrapper app to get the args and then call your app). If they don't (or there are only a few combinations) then you can setup a desktop icon that passes the correct args - one icon for each set of args.